# IF() Multiple Cells are equal then "TRUE" with only taking number values in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a formula to take only number formats from a row to in order to use an IF formula that illicit the value of "No" if all cells are equal to each other.

See a snippet of my file here:

[image]

The problem I am having is that the formula is taking the blank cells (no formats) and counting them in the equation still, so all of my values are "Yes". How do I let my formula only calculate from cells that have numbers in them for each row? I have tried the IFNUMBER(), IFEMPTY() etc... but I am not sure I am employing these correctly e.g. nesting into my formula. I need to ignore the blanks in each row.

Note: I need to only take the cells with number values. I have cleared the contents of values of the rows that do not have number values.

Here is the equation that I currently have:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(ROUND($E2,3)=ROUND($F2,3),ROUND($F2,3)=ROUND($G2,3),ROUND($G2,3)=ROUND($H2,3),ROUND($H2,3)=ROUND($I2,3),ROUND($I2,3)=ROUND($J2,3),ROUND($J2,3)=ROUND($K2,3),ROUND($K2,3)=ROUND($L2,3),ROUND($L2,3)=ROUND($M2,3),ROUND($M2,3)=ROUND($N2,3)),"No","Yes"),"")
```

Note: this is taking blanks and counting them (as stated from above). It should produce a "Yes" if there are numbers different in the column and a "No" if there are no numbers differences. Currently, it is always producing a "Yes" because it is counting the blanks in the columns.

I am open to a vba solution as well, I have the following from code, but I do not know how to set the range for each row to only look for number formats:

Here is my vba code:

```
Dim arng As Range
Dim aworkrng As Range
Dim brng As Range
Dim bworkrng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set aworkrng = Range("O2:O1550")
Set bworkrng = Range("E2:N1550")
Set brng = Range("E2:N2")
On Error Resume Next

For Each arng In aworkrng

        If Not IsEmpty(brng.Value) Then

 arng.Formula = _
    "=IFERROR(IF(AND(ROUND(RC5,3)=ROUND(RC6,3),ROUND(RC6,3)=ROUND(RC7,3),ROUND(RC7,3)=ROUND(RC8,3),ROUND(RC8,3)=ROUND(RC9,3),ROUND(RC9,3)=ROUND(RC10,3),ROUND(RC10,3)=ROUND(RC11,3),ROUND(RC11,3)=ROUND(RC12,3),ROUND(RC12,3)=ROUND(RC13,3),ROUND(RC13,3)=ROUND(RC14,3)),""No"",""Yes""),"""")"
Range("O3").Select

End If

Next
```

If anyone can help me on this, I would great appreciate it!

Comment: Did you try to wrap the cell reference with VALUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(MIN(E2:N2)=MAX(E2:N2),"No","Yes")
```